# Motivic Thom space of a trivial Bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homotopy-theory

I was trying to learn some motivic homotopy theory and I am stuck at this problem.

Let $p: E \rightarrow X$ be a Vector bundle over a smooth scheme X. We define Thom space $\textbf{Th(E) }$ := $E/E-i(X)$. Where $ i: X \rightarrow E$ is the zero section.

I was trying to compute the Thom space of a trivial bundle.

By definition, it must be $\mathbb{A}^n \times X/ (\mathbb{A}^n - \{ 0 \}) \times X. $. But how to prove that this is the same as $\mathbb{A}^n / \mathbb{A}^n - \{ 0 \} \wedge X_+$ ?

Probably it is trivial and I might be overlooking something. Is there some kinda 'excision' property at play here?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is it not just true that if $B \subseteq A$, then $(A \times X)/(B \times X) \cong A/B \wedge X_+$?

Comment: How do you prove that claim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a sketch of the claim I made in the comments.  It doesn't really have anything to do with (algebraic-geometry) or (homotopy-theory) - just some good old-fashioned (general-topology).

The claim we wish to show is:

> Let $B \subseteq A$.  Then $(A \times X)/(B \times X) \cong A/B \wedge X_+$.

First, note that from the definition it is easy to see that $A/B \wedge X_+ \cong (A/B \times X)/(B/B \times X)$.  Now consider the composite map $$A \times X \to A/B \times X \to (A/B \times X)/(B/B \times X) \cong A/B \wedge X_+.$$  This map sends $B \times X$ to the basepoint, so we get a map $(A \times X)/(B \times X) \to A/B \wedge X_+$, and I claim that this is a homeomorphism.  It's continuous and open by construction, and it's not hard to see that it's bijective. Perhaps drawing a couple of pictures would be more convincing.